# flutter get value from object and display in Text()

Tags: flutter

How to get value from an object in flutter? i need to display name of products in Text()

```
List<Object> _dataResponse = [
{"item":"chakka"},
{"item":"manga"},
{"item":"thenga"},
];

 ListView(
              children: _productName
                  .map((f) => ListTile(
                        leading:  Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.green,),
                        title:  **Text('$f["item"]')**,

                      ))
                  .toList(),
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex expressions (not just simple identifiers) you need to use `${...}` instead of `$...`

```
Text('${f["item"]}')
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed `List<Object>` to `List<Map>` too